# SQL COUNT - greater than some number without having to get the exact count?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

There's a thread at https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/issues/545 talking about a problem with a Ruby pagination gem when it encounters large tables.

When the number of records is large, the pagination will display something like:

> [1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][...][end]

This can incur performance penalties when the number of records is huge, because getting an exact count of, say, 50M+ records will take time. However, all that's needed to know in this case is that the count is greater than `the number of pages to show * number of records per page`.

Is there a faster SQL operation than getting the *exact* `COUNT`, which would merely assert that the `COUNT` is greater than some value *x*?

Comment: What's DB client you are using.. Postgresql, MySql .. which one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with

SQL Server:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM MyTable) X
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM MyTable LIMIT 1000) X
```

With a little luck, the SQL Server/MySQL will optimize this query. Clearly instead of 1000 you should put the maximum number of pages you want * the number of rows per page.

Comment: `TOP` function from which DB engine ? Do you have a generic solution, which can be used across the DB ?